# Why does Files.delete throw a FileSystemException

Tags: java, file, unix, nio, file-permissions

When I run:

```
Files.delete(Paths.get(filepath));
```

I get:

```
    java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /tmp/some-file: OperationNotPermitted                 
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126) ~[?:1.8.0_102]                        
   ...
```

The file has permissions:

```
-rw-rw-rw-   some-user-1 some-group
```

and `lsattr` shows that it's not immutable:

```
-------------e-
```

The Java code is turned into script that does some stuff and ultimately runs `java` on SpringLauncher:

```
sudo -u some-user-2 the-script
```

`some-user-2` is not in some-group, but the file has user write permissions and `/tmp/` has 777 permissions, so why am I not able to delete it in Java?

When I change the user (`chown /tmp/some-file some-user-2`), I am able to delete it with the above Java code.  This also confuses me.

Comment: Can you `rm` the file from the command line? If not, then the problem is nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Also the likely reason is that /tmp has the sticky permission bit set.

Comment: When I run `sudo -u some-user-2 rm /tmp/some-file`, it tells me "Operation not permitted."  So yeah, it seems like Java is not the culprit

Comment: I did the `rm`, just copied it wrong.  Will edit.  It looks like the /tmp/ sticky bit is indeed set (I see a "t" at the end of the bits).

Comment: Just changed the sticky bit with `sudo chmod -t /tmp`.  Then ran `rm`.  It worked after that, so it seems like the sticky bit was the issue.  You learn something new everyday

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work for more information

Comment: @Lycus Of course, with that bit unset anyone can delete anyone else's temporary files...

Comment: To delete a file from a directory in Unix-like systems, you also need write access to the directory itself, not only to the file.